# Understanding behaviour of full height background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a background image that takes up the height of the viewport.  I have noticed some strange behaviour I was hoping someone would explain.  So I simply have

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <header class="header"></header>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now I want to make the header have a background image that is the full height of the viewport.  As such, I do the following

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header{
    background: url("../images/1.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
}
```

Now when I do this, I get a blank page.  Now this is the part I am trying to understand.  If I change the height to `100vh` it works.  However, if I keep it at `100%` and remove the div with the class main, it works.

Now I know that it will be 100% of its parent tag, but the div with the class main does not specify a height, so shouldnt this then inherit 100% of the body tag, which takes up the whole viewport?  Obviously I can give main a height of 100% and then everything works as expected, just wondering why it doesnt obtain it from the body when no height is specified.  Also wondering why 100vh works?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: body doesnt' take 100% of the height, its height is the height of its elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.main` container CSS is missing

```
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.header{
    background: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/any");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <header class="header"></header>
</div>
```

The header fills its direct parent: main, if you didn't set this div to fill the body that's the problem.

It's also a good idea to set margin and padding to 0 in the body:

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```